# php form post, does not refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, refresh

My problem is that my html/php form does not 'refresh' when posted. I have been working around this by doing a 'meta refresh' but recently encountered a problem when I wanted to echo something, and it would never been seen because of the 'meta refresh' I've tried a few things with no luck, here is the code.

```
<?php //SESSION START
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['username']){
        //grant access
    }else{
        header('Location: login.html');
    }
    if(session_is_registered(username)){
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        if ($username!==Administrator){
            //grant access
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8 />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_style.css" />
        <title>XYZ Car Rental - Rent a Car</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <span style="color:#38C0CC;">XYZ</span> Car Rental
            </div>
            <div id="banner"><?php echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username'].". "?></div>
            <!--Greets user with "Welcome 'username'"-->
            <div id="navbar">
                <?php //navigation bar privaledges
                    if(session_is_registered(username)){//if logged in
                        $username = $_SESSION['username'];//creates variable: username
                        if ($username==Administrator){//if the username is equal to 'Administrator' show the following navigation
                ?>
                <a href="index.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/home.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="add_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/insert_car.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="remove_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/remove_car.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="update_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/update_car.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="view_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/view_cars.jpg" /></div></a>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
                <a href="add_user.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/add_user.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="remove_user.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/remove_user.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="update_user.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/update_user.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="view_user.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/view_users.jpg" /></div></a>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
                <a href="logout.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/logout.jpg" /></div></a>
                <?php }else{ //else, show the navigation bar for a user ?>
                <a href="index.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/home.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="rent_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/rent_car_s.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="return_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/return_car.jpg" /></div></a>
                <a href="view_car.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/view_cars.jpg" /></div></a>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
                <a href="logout.php"><div class="button"><img src="images/logout.jpg" /></div></a>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                //close if's
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <span style="font-size:28px;">Rent Cars</span>
                <hr />
                <?php
                    $link = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "password");//connect to database
                    mysql_select_db ("cardatabase");//select database
                    $query = "SELECT * from cars";//select all from table, cars
                    $result = mysql_query ($query, $link);//result = query

                    $available = $_POST[available];
                    //$available = the posted available

                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){//if submit is pressed, execute

                        if($available>0){//if there is a car avaialble of that type
                            //add one of those cars to the table, rentedcars
                            //include the name of the users session for extra purposes
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO rentedcars(REAL_ID,ID,CARMAKE,CARMODEL,FUELTYPE,TRANSMISSION,ENGINESIZE,DOORS,DATEADDED,USERNAME) SELECT '',id,carmake,carmodel,fueltype,transmission,enginesize,doors,dateadded,'$username' FROM cars WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
                            //after it has been added, run another query to reduce the 'available' by 1
                            //available = available - 1
                            mysql_query ("UPDATE cars SET available=available-1 WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
                            //echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=rent_car.php'/>";
                            //refresh the page after it is complete
                            $success = "Car Rented.";

                        }else{//if the 'available' == 0
                            $error = "There is no more cars of that type available.";
                            //creates a variable, to be printed in a different div
                            //all of that type are no longer available
                            //stops renting cars below 0
                        }
                    }

                    //echos the table & titles
                    echo "<table cellspacing=3 border=1 style='font-size:13px;background-color:white;'>
                        <tr style='background-color:#38C0CC;'>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Make</td>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>Fuel Type</td>
                        <td>Transmission</td>
                        <td>Engine Size</td>
                        <td>Doors</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Date Added</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Rent</td>
                        </tr>";


                    //while loop to display data from the database into a form
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<form action=rent_car.php method=post>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=id value=".$row['ID'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=carmake value=".$row['CARMAKE'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=carmodel value=".$row['CARMODEL'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=fueltype value=".$row['FUELTYPE'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=transmission value=".$row['TRANSMISSION'].">" . " </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=enginesize value=".$row['ENGINESIZE'].">" . " </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=doors value=".$row['DOORS'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=amount value=".$row['AMOUNT'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=available value=".$row['AVAILABLE'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=dateadded value=".$row['DATEADDED'].">"." </td>";//value = database value
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=hidden name=hidden value=".$row['ID'].">"." </td>";//hidden value
                        //hidden value helps target the ID value when it is not available
                        echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=submit value=Rent>"." </td>";//submit
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</form>";
                    }
                    //close while loop
                    echo "</table>";
                    //close table
                ?>
                <div id="errorbox">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                    <!--echos the error-->
                    <!--no more cars available-->
                </div>

                <div id="successbox">
                    <?php echo $success; ?>
                    <!--echos the success-->
                    <!car has been rented-->
                </div>
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both;" />
            <!--clears the float-->
            <div id="footer">
                XYZ Car Rental™
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know the code is a bit of a headache, any help would be great!

Comment: You are missing quite a bit of quotes... `if ($username==Administrator){` should be `if($username == "Administrator"){}`.. but thats just 1 thing.. `session_is_registered(username)` should be `session_is_registered("username")`   loads more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loads of problems here.

Firstly, you're using mysql_* when you should be using PDO or MySQLi. See [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Secondly,

```
echo "<form action=rent_car.php method=post>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<form action='rent_car.php' method='POST'>";
```

Thirdly, you're using constants instead of strings:

```
if ($username!==Administrator){
```

Should be

```
if ($username!=='Administrator'){
```

Fourthly, you're vulnerable to SQLi attacks:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE cars SET available=available-1 WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rentedcars(REAL_ID,ID,CARMAKE,CARMODEL,FUELTYPE,TRANSMISSION,ENGINESIZE,DOORS,DATEADDED,USERNAME) SELECT '',id,carmake,carmodel,fueltype,transmission,enginesize,doors,dateadded,'$username' FROM cars WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
```

You're also lacking quotes in many more places.

The reason for why you have to refresh the page again, to see the updated content is because you're fetching data before you update. Do it the other way round. Update the data first, then fetch:

So have this:

```
$result = mysql_query ($query, $link);//result = query
```

Below your `if` to check if anything was POSTed:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){//if submit is pressed, execute
```

Have the select query below that IF. That should fix the current problem. But please, don't ignore all the others.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but would any of this fix my initial problem?

Comment: The second issue I mentioned could be your problem.

Comment: Afraid not, corrected it already

Comment: Let me just confirm; You're saying when you hit the submit on `<form action=rent_car.php method=post>`, nothing happens?

Comment: Do you have a live version I can look at?

Comment: Well, it echoes the appropriate message, but the contents of the form do not update, and I need to manually refresh to see the updated contents

Comment: Afraid I don't have anywhere to host

Comment: Right, so the problem is that you have to refresh again (after submitting) to see the content updated, right?

Comment: It is the entire logic of the page. You should do all of the other updating and inserting first based on If post is set and the actual call to fill the form should be the last option right before the form is loaded

Comment: Correct, and that wouldent be a problem, but I'd like to echo some code, but if I insert a 'meta refresh' the echo would not be seen, so I have to sort the initial problem out instead

Comment: And thank you for your additional help :p